# Kibana dashboard ideas

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, elk

Anyone has any ideas of Kibana dashboards I can create from Syslogs/eventlogs? Help much appreciated. I thought of creating a dashboard that detects malware but im not sure what I can do with the different event logs or how to visualise and detect malware/

Answer (score 0):

MachineLearning feature in kibana would detect the malware in syslog/eventlogs.

Go to kibana -> in search bar (search for detections) or go to security -> overview -> in that page you could see a tab called "detections" --> in that detections page now click "**Manage detection rules**" which would provide you the prebuilt malware detection rules which might help you.

Also there are no default kibana dashboard thus it should be create on our own.

I hope this answer would help you

Keep Posted!!! Thanks !!!